# Pixelated launcher icons in the launcher

Tags: launcher

After upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04.1, the launcher icons are pixelated.

An extra reboot did not resolve the issue.

The only relevant customization I can think of is that I adjusted DPI settings in 12.04, although I don't remember exactly what settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing this question, I opened the settings manager. Simply opening the appearance tab (where launcher icon size is a perhaps relevant option) caused the icons to revert to normal.

Comment: This problem occurred for me after updating the kernel, and changing the icon size fixed the problem, but at some sizes the icons remain pixelated.